# How to implement a DataList component in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm working on a webapp and i wonder if there's any chance to implement the following HTML element in Spring MVC?

```
<input list="browsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want on your jsp pages.

For example:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="recipe" action="${home}/admin/recipes">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><s:message code="recipe.title" />*</label>
        <form:input path="title" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="title" cssClass="error-help" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <s:message code="add" var="addLabel" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="${addLabel}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" list="datalist" name="data" required placeholder="<s:message code='user.email' />" value="${userEmail}" />
            <datalist id="datalist">
                    <option value="first" />
                    <option value="second" />
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Here we have model object "recipe" with field "title" and field "data" with datalist

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/recipes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(
        @ModelAttribute("recipe") @Valid Recipe recipe,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        @RequestParam("data") String data,
        Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(model, recipe);
        return "admin:/recipes/add";
    }

    System.out.println(data);
    recipe = recipeService.create(recipe);
    return "redirect:/admin/recipes/" + recipe.getId();
}
```

You can choose "first" or "second" for "data" input and it will be printed out on server-side